# How do I create URL shortcut for Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, shortcut

I have a PowerShell script that opens a certain link inside of Internet Explorer. So far I have the following code. It opens the link but it sends to my default browser when I specifically need it to open in Internet Explorer.

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop\TMW.lnk")
$ShortCut.TargetPath="http://tmw1.casttrans.com/rdweb"
$ShortCut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer";
$ShortCut.WindowStyle = 1;
$ShortCut.IconLocation = "iexplore.exe, 0";

$ShortCut.Save()
```

Comment: Rather than making an URL shortcut, you will need to be make a shortcut to `iexplore.exe` and pass the website as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URL shortcuts open with the Default Browser. To open with a specific browser, you will need to call that application and pass it the webpage. In particular, `iexplore.exe` opens the webpage passed in the first argument.

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$ShortCut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop\TMW.lnk")
$ShortCut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
$ShortCut.Arguments = "http://tmw1.casttrans.com/rdweb"
$ShortCut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer"
$ShortCut.WindowStyle = 1
$ShortCut.IconLocation = "iexplore.exe, 0"

$ShortCut.Save()
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you put the `;` only at the end of the last 3 lines before you `$ShortCut.Save()` ?

Comment: @Danijel-JamesW It was the copy-paste from the question, they are completely superfluous since each statement is on separate lines.. Answer edited to remove.